# Cloning a gem to a local file isn't detecting my changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I need to make changed to the Twitter gem, so I cloned it to a local folder, then changed my bundle file like so:

```
gem 'twitter', :path => '~/code/twitter-ruby'
```

I added a new method, and ran a test that simply calls the method, to start off with. But I get an error of `undefined method`. In other words, it hasn't detected my changes. I tried commenting out a whole file, ran my other tests and those all worked, as though the file were still there.

In my project I'm still importing as `require 'twitter'`.

I've tried running `bundle update twitter`, I've tried removing it from the bundle, I've tried increasing the version number (which it does detect, and updates to the most recent version), I've tried committing my changes to GIT. Nothing seems to work - I just keep getting the same `undefined method` error. Any ideas?

EDIT: my Gemfile.lock:

```
PATH
  remote: /Users/Andrew/code/twitter
  specs:
    twitter (5.15.0)
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES

  twitter!

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.4
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was using bundle to install the gems, but I wasn't using `bundle exec` to run my application. It became clear after running the uninstall suggestion and the `require my_lib` line starting to fail inside `irb`. `bundle exec irb` allowed it to work using the gem path defined in the Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

First uninstall the `twitter` gem, by doing `gem uninstall twitter`, then do `bundle install`

Comment: On doing this, in the console I get: "Using twitter 5.15.0 from source at '~/code/twitter-ruby'". Then when I run the test, I get "cannot load such file -- twitter (LoadError)"

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the branch name too.

```
gem 'twitter', path: <absolute-path-to-your-local-twitter-repo>, branch: <branch-name>
```

**EDIT**

e.g. path as "/Users/me/path/to/repo"

And run

```
bundle update twitter
```

Then restart server, if running as a web application.

Comment: After doing `gem uninstall twitter` as suggested in another answer, I now get "cannot load such file -- twitter (LoadError)" when I run my test, even after following your suggestion. It's really bizarre. When I do `bundle update twitter` it lets me know where it's using twitter from, and what version it finds there.

Comment: When you run `bundle update twitter`, do you see your local path to repo on the trerminal? Also, please check `Gemfile.lock` after this update and see where is it picking `twitter` gem from?

Comment: Make sure your local fork repo is named `twitter`. I mean the directory name.

Comment: I do see my local path in terminal. "Using twitter 5.15.0 from source at `/Users/Andrew/code/twitter`" I renamed it and still getting the same result.

Comment: Edited my gemfile.lock into my question.